# Meteor - Meteor.Collection.get not defined in production

Tags: javascript, meteor, dev-to-production

I'm trying to use `Meteor.Collection.get(collection_name)` (server side only) in production, it works well in development ; but as soon as I try to build my app with `meteor --production`, meteor throw

> TypeError: Meteor.Collection.get is not a function

I suppose that Meteor.Collection.get was only made for debugging purposes (I can't find anything about it in the official documentation). Any idea how I can use it in production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, where `Meteor.Collection.get` comes from in your code but I know the very reliable and long time battle proof `dburles:mongo-collection-instances` which allows you to retrieve a Mongo.Collection via it's name.

Add the package:

```
meteor add dburles:mongo-collection-instances
```

Create a collection:

```
// server/client
export const MyDocs = new Mongo.Collection('myDocs')
```

Get the collection:

```
// anywhere else
const MyDocs = Mongo.Collection.get('myDocs')
```

It works on the server and the client and runs fine in production.

Documentation: https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances

**Edit: A note on `--production`**

This flag is only there to simulate production minifaction. See the important message here in the docs: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#never-use-production-flag

You should always use `meteor build` to build a production node app. More to read here: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#custom-deployment

Comment: Thanks, I did tried this package already, this package is slowing down the server (at least 2 or 3 times slower than usual). I'm currently searching for the definition in my sources (can't find it yet)

Comment: Did you read the links on production build and the `--production` flag?

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm using the --production flag for performances tests, i'm not going to use it for deployment

Comment: It seems that it's linked with my environment, when being in dev mode the sources of the project are build with my computer meteor sources (not the project's ones) which contains the dburles:mongo-collection-instances package (I don't know why exactly). So I reinstalled the package on the project and now it's working fine (the server isn't slow anymore). Thank you anyway !